# Replace an null element in a list with a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have an issue in the code snippet below:

I have a list of list, some of which is empty. First I want to replace the empty value with a value and then flatten it.

Here's the code snippet:

```
a = [['3'] , ['4'], [], ['6']]  #I want to get ['3', '4', 0 , 6]

flat = ['0' if i == '[]' else i for element in a for i in element]
```

But I'm unable to get the result. Kindly help

Comment: You might want to keep strings: `[v[0] if v else '0' for v in a]`

Comment: why are some resulting values mutated to strings?

Comment: Thanks @Matthias, you literally saved my life

Comment: `[]` and `'[]'` are two very different values.

Comment: This is where I wish `list` had a `get` method: `[v.get(0, '0') for v in a]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use next with a default value

```
flat = [next(x, "0") for x in a]
```

or just the fact that an empty list is falsy

```
flat = [x[0] if x else "0" for x in a]
```

Comment: Didn't know you could use `next` like that. That's really useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code,

Code1 -

```
a = [['3'] , ['4'], [], ['6']]  #I want to get ['3', '4', 0 , 6]
updated = [val[0] if val else '0' for val in a]
print(updated)
```

Code2 (For understanding purpose in a long form) -

```
a = [['3'] , ['4'], [], ['6']]  #I want to get ['3', '4', 0 , 6]

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == []:
        a[i] = '0'
    else:
        a[i] = a[i][0]
print(a)
```

Both the above code fulfills your requirment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to flatten it to a 1-dimensional array, but it doesn't replace the empty array as 0.

```
from itertools import chain

a = [
    ['3'],
    ['4'],
    [],
    ['6']
]

flatten_list = list(chain.from_iterable(a))

print(flatten_list)
```